# Trying to get usb event logs with pywin32 on windows

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

Hi I am trying to extract and print all the usb event logs with python, and a library called pywin32, but i cant point exactly to only usb event logs in the registry. Any idea on pywin32? Also the documention that comes with pywin32 is quite outdated

Comment: Please, show us some of your code. Read this guide: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @stjepano thanks a lot. i later came across a library python library,  [python-evt](https://github.com/williballenthin/python-evt)  and i manades to access the logs. Cheers